# PostgreSQL epoch time conversion

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, epoch

I am using the postgresSQL function to_timestamp(double precision) to convert from epoch time to normal timestamp but I am facing a problem where the timestamp is incorrect

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1428058548491);
```

produces "47223-05-17 12:08:11.000064+02"

while it should be 4/3/2015, 12:55:48 PM GMT+2:00 DST

```
SELCT to_timestamp(1428058557697);
```

produces "47223-05-17 14:41:36.999936+02"

while it should be 4/3/2015, 12:55:57

as can be seen the dates have been converted totally incorrect

Comment: `$ date --date="@1428058548491"
Wed, May 17, 47223  6:08:11 AM`

Your "epoch time" appears not to be the expected, standard Unix epoch. What platform is it from?

Comment: `to_timestamp()` expects seconds, not milliseconds: `SELECT to_timestamp(1428058548491 / 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was explained from people In the comments for people who get the same problem. The function to_timestamp() expects it in seconds not milliseconds therefore that is the solution.

[Quote from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

> it accepts a double precision argument and converts from Unix epoch (**seconds** since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to timestamp with time zone